# How to solve 'invalid locator' problem during "click a button problem" in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a button that html is below

[image]

I tired the following code

```
Execute_Button = driver.find_element("xPath",'//button[text()="Execute "]')
```

But Python comes up with this error message. How to solve?

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs ([locating elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)), locating by xpath can be done using locator `By.XPATH` or `'xpath'`. In your code you use `'xPath'`, which is invalid. To fix that simply change it to one of the two I mentioned, i.e.

```
Execute_Button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="Execute "]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Execute "]').click()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.